# How to track related entities with LoadProperty method in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf, api

I am using LoadProperty to load the property of an related entity using QueryOperationResponse class.

Here is the code :

```
QueryOperationResponse<T> response= _context.LoadProperty(job, "Parts", token) as QueryOperationResponse<T>;
```

Here Parts is related entity of Job Entity and it is also an property of this.
If I use the above code, I got an exception "the context is not currently tracking the entity".

Can anybody help me?

Manoj

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I solved this problem by reusing the same context object.

Example:

```
MyContext proxy = new MyContext(new Uri("http://localhost:62717/MyService.svc/", UriKind.Absolute));
var MyEntity = proxy.MyEntity.Where(x=>x.id = 1).First();
// ...
// Later in the code:
// A new proxy is created. This will cause the failure in the next line.
proxy = new MyContext(new Uri("http://localhost:62717/MyService.svc/", UriKind.Absolute));
proxy.LoadProperty(MyEntity, "RelatedEntity");
// Make sure you reuse the same proxy as the one you loaded your MyEntity object.
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was able fix the problem using the same context object. Again thanks for the reply.